# Using MS Graph API to add more app roles to an app registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is there any way I can create additional app role using MS Graph API. I already have one app role in my app registration, but required to create additional app roles. PATCH does not work to create additional app roles and gives error:

Doing a patch in the postman as:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/11e8abb0-zzzz-4a5d-bf02-zzzzzzzzz

{
    "appRoles": [
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "Application"
            ],
            "description": "TestRole",
            "displayName": "TestRole",
            "id": "{{$guid}}",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "TestRole"
        }
    ]
}

Getting a response:

{
    "error": {
        "code": "CannotDeleteOrUpdateEnabledEntitlement",
        "message": "Permission (scope or role) cannot be deleted or updated unless disabled first.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-10-27T08:18:30",
            "request-id": "5e8b5997-bd4f-4716-a090-10e22f50c49d",
            "client-request-id": "5e8b5997-bd4f-4716-a090-10e22f50c49d"
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting a new app role to be added to the app registration.
Hope this code helps.

image:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwhhS.png)

Comment: Instead of screenshot, please add the request URL, body and error message as code block.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @GauravMantri: Request body : `{"appRoles": [{"allowedMemberTypes":  "Application"],"description": "TestRole", "displayName": "TestRole","id":{{$guid}}","isEnabled": true,"origin": "Application", "value": "TestRole"} ]}`  request_url - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/11e8abb0-0089-4a5d-bf02-013f5d06c43a (PATCH)

Comment: This gives 400 bad request: `{"error": { "code":"CannotDeleteOrUpdateEnabledEntitlement",
 "message": "Permission (scope or role) cannot be deleted or updated unless disabled first." ...}}.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue it seems.

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft Graph is a RESTful web API that enables you to access Microsoft Cloud service resources. After you register your app and get authentication tokens for a user or service, you can make requests to the
Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: This does not really answer OP’s problem.

Comment: This is a simple statement of what Microsoft Graph is.  It does not answer the question.